# Only print a-m and A-M lines

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to only print lines at only consist of `a-m` and `A-M`, but in the below example I also get the first line, which I shouldn't as it contains `t`.

```
~$ echo -e 'a t\nb\nt' > /tmp/file.txt
~$ perl -ne '/^[a-mA-M]+/ && print' /tmp/file.txt 
a t
b
~$
```

**Question**

How do I only print lines that just contains `a-m` and `A-M`?

Comment: /^[a-m]/i should do it.  Unless you mean the string "a-m" and "A-M".  In that case it would be /^[aA]-[mM]/

Comment: You need to anchor your regex to the end of the line as well: `/^[a-m]+$/i` (the `i` flag makes the match case insensitive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `$` anchor to your regex:

```
^[a-mA-M]+$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/vK2rN8/1)**

[image]

Since your regex is `^[a-mA-M]+` it matches `a` in your text, that's why it prints the line that contains it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified anything after the `+` that needs to match.  This means that `/^[a-m]+/i` matches the same lines as `/^[a-m]/i`.  You need to specify that the match must extend to the end of the string by using the end-of-line metacharacter `$`:

```
perl -ne '/^[a-m]+$/i && print' /tmp/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (possibly simpler) option is to invert the logic and ignore lines that include characters outside of your set.

```
perl -ne '/[^a-m]/i || print' /tmp/file.txt
```

Switching the `&&` to `||` inverts the logic and we now no longer need to anchor the regex as a non-matching character can appear anywhere in the string.

The `^` at the start of the character class inverts the class. i.e. it means "all characters not in the given range".